# Calling a function from within a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I am connecting to a server with ssh using the `connect6` function, then I have to call the `operations` function from within the `connect6` function which further runs its commands.

If I put all the `operation` function commands into `connect6` functions I am getting the desired output, otherwise I get an error: `No file or directory`.

```
connect6 () {
ssh -q root@example.com << EOF
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Successfully Logged into the Server"
else
    echo "Check your credentials"
    exit
fi
$(operations)
EOF
}

operations(){
        cd /var/dist/test/
        sudo ./o
        echo "line 2 line 3" | sudo tee -a test.323
        sudo ./c
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operations()` function is defined in your local shell.

The things in your here document are being passed to your remote shell's standard input.

Since your local shell and your remote shell are two different processes, this basically means you're asking your remote shell to run a function you've never told it about. Since it doesn't know of a function or alias called `operations`, it falls back to searching through your (remote) `PATH` and, upon failing to find a matching program, throws the error you're seeing.

Three possible solutions:

1. Include the body of `operations()` in your here document and don't bother with a function, as you've already found works.
2. Include the entire definition of `operations()` in your here document. I'm not sure if this gains you much in this particular case over option 1, but in a longer script or if you reuse `operations()` it might be more helpful.
3. Add the `operations()` definition to your .bashrc or similar autoloaded file on the remote computer. This will mean you can drop the definition from your script here.